# Rendering PDF documents in bulk in Django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I need to generate a whole heap (~200) of PDF docs through Django and am looking for suggestions (or a library) to do this. There needs to be a view for each individual document, but will periodically need to download all of the pdfs generated by this view from a particular filter. I can see these possible approaches:

- Generate a single document - this is easy, but I would prefer individual documents
- Generate one document with a 'download' content-disposition, then redirect to the next one (not sure if this will work for 200 docs?)
- Generate/cache all docs on the server in a background task, then provide a zip-file link, or save to an external storage such as Google Drive.

For the third option, what PDF libraries are well suited to provide both programmatic rendering in a background task, but also make it easy to view a single document on-demand?

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [reportlab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab) in a django app (albeit years ago) and it did a great job rendering templated HTML into PDF for download.

**Single documents**

If this takes less than a couple of seconds, probably fine as part of the request/response cycle.

**Bulk zipped documents**

To avoid tying up your web workers on long running tasks, you'd typically pushed this kind of heftier work into an async task queue, then provide the user with a link once their download is ready and waiting in storage. That said, it depends on your use case. If you're sure you'll only have a few concurrent users, you could potentially justify skipping the additional complexity of the queue. If you're not sure, it's probably worth biting the bullet and setting up a queue.

Good news is, if you go the queue route you'll likely find additional use cases for it pretty quickly. :) For django, [celery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery) with [redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis) is a solid combo.